# Text to Speech from AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

Is it possible do to TTS from a Widget? The same question has been asked before, but no real answer has been given. I would like to start TTS when a Widget is pressed, and say some text. And how would this be done?

Comment: I can't see why not. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've followed this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/ but a new instance of TextToSpeech can't even be created.

Comment: Please up-vote and accept an answer if you get any answer which is help you in development.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah definitely it is possible, first thing you need to implement "OnInitListener" in you activity and write below code inside your activity..

```
TextToSpeech talker;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    talker = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
}

public void say(String text2say){
    talker.speak(text2say, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    say("Hello World");

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (talker != null) {
        talker.stop();
        talker.shutdown();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

for more help follow   [this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine/)

Comment: Where would I put this code? In the AppWidgetProvider, Configuration activity or create a seperate Activity?

Comment: The question asks about an AppWidgetProvider, not an Activity.